# How do I mock the "file_system" service?

Tags: testing

How do I mock the *file_system* service in PHPUnit?

The issue is being reproduced when `\Drupal::service('file_system')` is executing in the test suite environment.  If `\Drupal::service('file_system')` is removed the class loads the assertions in the test class run perfectly. My belief is that this service needs to be mocked. (This could be completely false. I am really unsure).

The terminal error displayed when running the test is the following.

> Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerNotInitializedException: \Drupal::$container is not initialized yet. \Drupal::setContainer()

This is the class method that executes the Drupal 8 service.

```
 /**
   * @inheritdoc
   */
  public function setBasePath($path = Null) {

    if ($path !== Null) {
      $this->directories['base'] = $path;
    } else{
     $this->directories['base'] = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath(file_default_scheme() . "://");
    }
  }
```

This is the test class that is going to test the above class in the future. Right now it compares a string only.

```
/**
 *
 * @group react_forms
 */
class DirectoryStructureTest extends \Drupal\Tests\UnitTestCase {

  /**
   * @var object
   */
  private $objToTest;


  /**
   *
   */
  public function setUp() {
    $this->objToTest = new DirectoryStructure();
  }


  public function testGetDirectories() {

    $this->assertEquals('this', 'this');
  }


  /**
   * Once test method has finished running, whether it succeeded or failed,
   * tearDown() will be invoked. Unset the unit created object.
   */
  public function tearDown() {
    unset($this->objToTest);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't call `file_system` with `\Drupal::service('file_system')` use dependency injection instead:

So try something like the following in your service:

1. Add arguments to your `*.services.yml` file.

```
services:
  yourModule.yourService:
    class: Drupal\yourModule\yourServiceClass
    arguments: ['@file_system']
```

2. Inject the `file_system` service in your Class:

```
  use Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface;

  /**
   * The file system service.
   * @var \Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface
   */
  protected $fileSystem;
  /**
  * Class constructor.
  * @param \Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface $file_system
  */
  public function __construct(FileSystemInterface $file_system) {;
    $this->fileSystem = $file_system;
  }
```

9. Change `setBasePath` method to be like.

```
  /**
   * @inheritdoc
   */
  public function setBasePath($path = Null) {

    if ($path !== Null) {
      $this->directories['base'] = $path;
    } else{
     $this->directories['base'] = $this->fileSystem->realpath(file_default_scheme() . "://");
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are welcome, i'm glad that help.